# What is the C# equivalent of C++ DWORD?

Tags: c#, c++

After searching, I heard that UInt32 was the C# equivalent of C++ DWORD.
I tested results by performing the arithmetic

```
*(DWORD*)(1 + 0x2C) //C++
(UInt32)(1 + 0x2C) //C#
```

They produce completely different results. Can someone please tell me the correct match for DWORD in C#?

Comment: They definitely won't produce completely different results from arithmetic side, but I think you're misunderstanding the C++ code... Also C++ has no concept of DWORD, you're probably mixing Windows definitions in.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your example is using the `DWORD` as a pointer, which is most likely an invalid pointer. I'm assuming you meant `DWORD` by itself.

`DWORD` is defined as [`unsigned long`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx), which ends up being a 32-bit unsigned integer.

`uint` (`System.UInt32`) should be a match.

```
#import <stdio.h>

// I'm on macOS right now, so I'm defining DWORD
// the way that Win32 defines it.
typedef unsigned long DWORD;

int main() {
    DWORD d = (DWORD)(1 + 0x2C);
    int i = (int)d;
    printf("value: %d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Output: 45

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        uint d = (uint)(1 + 0x2C);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}", d);
    }
}
```

Output: 45

Comment: `System.UInt32` is a 64-bit unsigned integer? That's a pretty unfortunate name if that is true.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Nope, that was a typo, sorry

Comment: @StephenJennings So `ulong (System.UInt64)` should be the match then?

Comment: @Sphynx No, an unsigned long in C++ is a 32-bit unsigned integer, and the documentation I linked to confirms that DWORD is a 32-bit unsigned integer. It's not the same as a ulong in C#, which is a 64-bit unsigned integer.

Answer (score 0):

Your two snippets do completely different things. In your C++ code, you are, for some strange reason, converting the value `(1 + 0x2C)` *(a strange way to write 45)* to a `DWORD*`, and then dereferencing it, as if that address is actually a valid memory location. With the C#, you are simply converting between integer types.

Answer (score 0):

**DWord definition from microsoft:**

typedef unsigned long DWORD, *PDWORD, *LPDWORD;
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230318.aspx

**Uint32 definition from microsoft**

typedef unsigned int UINT32;
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230386.aspx

now you can see the difference.... one is unsigned long and the other is unsigned int

Comment: The page you link to is for the C++ type UINT32, not for the C# type UInt32.

Comment: yes. But microsoft will maintain their ground level definitions right

Comment: C# has no type named `unsigned int` or `unsigned long`. They have `uint` and `ulong`, but those mean distinctly different things than `unsigned int` and `unsigned long` from C++. Specifically, the C# types have standard specified bit-sizes, whereas the C++ types may vary from platform to platform, and as it turns out, in Microsoft's compiler, `unsigned int` and `unsigned long` are the same size.

Comment: "unsigned int and unsigned long are the same size". Wont it vary with 64bit vs 32 bit architecture?

Comment: It's up to the compiler. And in the case of VC++, they are the both 32 bit, regardless of architecture.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks Benjamin

Comment: That's confusing. So an `unsigned long` is 32-bit?  Link says: *"A DWORD is a 32-bit unsigned integer"* then type: `typedef unsigned long DWORD, *PDWORD, *LPDWORD;`