# Second value not getting passed to C++ function during pinvoke

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, pinvoke

I have a c++ function which I am calling from c# using pinInvoke. Following is my cpp method-

```
int test(DWORD verb,DWORD verb2 )
{
    return verb2 *100;
}
```

My function is exposed as -

```
extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) int test(DWORD verb, DWORD verb2);
}
```

Following is my c# code where I am calling the above method:

```
public class API
{
    [DllImport("mydll.dll", EntryPoint = "test", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public static extern uint test(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U8)]ulong verb,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U8)]ulong verb2);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        uint x = DPAPI.test(26,10);
        Console.Write("result is-"+x);
    }
}
```

Here the second value is getting passed as 0,so wrong result is coming. Am I doing something wrong while passing the value?

What I have tried:

I am relatively new to Pinvoke. So I tried debugging to see whether the value is not getting passed to c++ code or whether the c++ code is not returning proper values.I found that the value getting passed itself was wrong.

Comment: This link could help you:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39951473/what-is-the-c-sharp-equivalent-of-c-dword

Comment: I do not think its type is the issue here as the first value is getting passed correctly.

Comment: @SomeshDhal Well, seeing as the type you are using is twice as wide memory-wise as the type you should be using, it certainly wouldn't be helping.

Comment: The value gets passed on the stack. The function receives two 32 bit values. So it takes 64 bits from the stack. That means it interprets the first 64 bit value that you pass as two separate 32 bit values. If you were running with the stack imbalance MDA enabled your would receive a warning about stack imbalance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DWORD` is a 32 but unsigned integer. You are mapping that to a 64 bit type. That is the problem. Your p/invoke should be:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int test(uint verb, uint verb2);
```

Note that I removed the needless `EntryPoint` and the erroneous `SetLastError` from the `DllImport` attribute.

I also wonder why you have selected `DWORD`. Unless you are passing those values onto Win32 functions it would likely make more sense to use intrinsic types. Why not use `int` or `unsigned int` in your C++ code?

Comment: That fixed it!!but how was the first variable getting the correct value?

Comment: I explained it in my comment to the question.

Comment: Not really sure there is such a place. One day I will write a guide on the subject covering all the issues that regularly come up ......

Comment: One more similar thing came up today..So I was passing a two values(long as unamanagedtype.I8 and int as unmanagedtype.I4) and in my c++ code both values were DWORD. As per your explanation above it should not have worked. But in my case it worked properly for 64 bit machine but in case of 32 bit second value was always coming as 0. I know what I did was wrong but would like to know why it behaved that way.Care to explain this behavior?

Comment: X64 calling convention passes parameters in registers

Comment: Still not clear on this. So,if parameters are passed in registers its size and marshaling rules are not respected?

Comment: No. Each parameter goes in a separate register. A 32 bit value fits in half of a 64 bit register. So if works by chance. Still, who cares about this. Reasoning about undefined behaviour is a little pointless.

Comment: Thanks Anyway for the useful insight!!I didn't find the registry passing anywhere.

Comment: Registry? What do you mean?

Comment: That by default x64 calling uses 4 registers to pass values from functions.Maybe I didn't know where to look.

Comment: It's on the calling conventions topic on MSDN